# Dagger 2 inject singleton without module

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I am using Dagger 2 injection to provide some dependency to client:

```
public class Dependency {

    @Inject
    Dependency() {
    }

    void check() {
        System.out.print("Instantiated");
    }
}

public class Client {

    @Inject Dependency dependency;

    Client() {
        ClientComponent component = DaggerClientComponent.create();
        component.inject(this);
    }

    void checkDependency() {
        dependency.check();
    }
}

@Component
public interface ClientComponent {
    void inject(Client client);
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        Client client = new Client();
        client.checkDependency();
    }
}
```

It works fine, but now I want to make my dependency singleton. How can I achieve it? Should I create module for this dependency and annotate provide method with singleton annotation or I have another options to avoid module creation?

Comment: Did you try my solution??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add @Singleton on the top of your class and add @Singleton annotation to your component.

```
@Singleton
public class Dependency {

    @Inject
    Dependency() {
    }

    void check() {
        System.out.print("Instantiated");
    }
}

@Singleton
@Component
public interface ClientComponent {
    void inject(Client client);
}
```

You should also move creation of your component to better place - onCreate method from app object is right place.

Comment: It works, thanks! Agree, injection inside constructor is a bad idea, I made it to reduce amount of code.